# Resolving Undefined Index error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following code in my php file:

```
$p_adminType = $_POST['adminType'];
$p_adminUserID = $_POST['userID'];
$p_adminUserPass = $_POST['userPass'];
$p_firstName = $_POST['adminFirstName'];
$p_lastName = $_POST['adminLastName'];
```

And then when I execute the file by clicking the submit button from an html file, I get a Notice Error saying:

```
Notice: Undefined index: userID in C:\wamp\www\CaNeCo\CaNeCo_Admin_Reg.php on line 19
Notice: Undefined index: userPass in C:\wamp\www\CaNeCo\CaNeCo_Admin_Reg.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: adminFirstName in C:\wamp\www\CaNeCo\CaNeCo_Admin_Reg.php on line 21
```

wherein you can see from the code where lines 19, 20, and 21 are. I tried adding isset() function to my code just like from what I have read from other sites/forums but when I do that, it doesn't solve my problem. It only hides the error message and the variables are still empty.

How can I resolve that problem? Also, I'm just wondering why is it only happening to 3 of the 5 declarations? `$p_adminType = $_POST['adminType'];` and `$p_lastName = $_POST['adminLastName'];` just work fine but not the other 3? Can someone please enlighten me about that?

This is the html file that I have:

```
<form method="post" action="CaNeCo_Admin_Reg.php">
  <table width="400">
  <tr>
      <td><b>Log-in Information:</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Administrator Type:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="adminType" id="adminType">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">Super Administrator</option>
        <option value="2">Administrator</option>
        <option value="3">Secretary</option>
        <option value="4">Viewer</option>
        </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>User ID: </td>
      <td><input type="text" name:"userID" id="adminUserID" placeholder="User I.D." maxlength="20" size="35"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Password: </td>
      <td><input type="password" name:"userPass" id="adminUserPass" placeholder="Password" maxlength="25" size="35"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Repeat Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="repeatPass" id="adminRepeatPass" placeholder="Repeat Password" maxlength="25" size="35"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="25"><b>Personal Information:</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>First Name: </td>
      <td><input type="text" name:"adminFirstName" id="adminFirstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" size="35"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Last Name: </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="adminLastName" id="adminLastName" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="25" size="35"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="50"><center><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></center></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `and the variables are still empty` how would your script know what the value should be if you're not passing it?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and check which variables are you getting.

Comment: First of all you need to make sure whether the name specified for the element on html  page is same as the one specified while accessing in php code

Comment: @Deval Shah - I've already added my form code.

Comment: @dreamweiver - i've double checked them already so i think there's no problem in that area.

Comment: @Dogbert - it seems that i don't understand what you said. if that's the case, why are the two other lines of codes that are similarly declared didn't have the same problems. I always test my code with dummy data so i'm pretty sure that they are not empty.

Comment: can anyone please try to answer this part of my post? _Also, I'm just wondering why is it only happening to 3 of the 5 declarations? $p_adminType = $_POST['adminType']; and $p_lastName = $_POST['adminLastName']; just work fine but not the other 3? Can someone please enlighten me about that?_

Comment: `name:"userID" ` you were suppose to use `name="userId"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined index is probably thrown because you don't have defined in your html form those names. Your form must look like this:

```
<input type='text' name='adminType'/>
<input type='text' name='userID'/>
<input type='text' name='userPass'/>
<input type='text' name='adminFirstName'/>
<input type='text' name='adminLastName'/>
```

Or whatever input `type` you are using. You should also post your form code to give more information.

Check that you have exactly those names defined in your html form.

**UPDATE**

You posted your form code and saw the error. You are using `:` instead to use `=` to asign values to your `name` properties for your inputs. If you take a look, the only 2 elements that you are recieving into the server are sent properly to the server, because you defined their name property like `name={value}` but the other 3 properties are defined as `name:{value}`. Assignament with `:` does not exist in HTML and the form dont know how to send that element with that attribute, so your server never recieves an element with an attribute named `userID`, because `userID` is not defined as already said (`name={value}`).

Comment: I've already double checked that area. so i'm pretty sure that there's no problem with that.

Comment: @Jairo My bad, I rewrited my answer. I didn't want to reference that. You have an error in your properties, you are using `:` instead an `=` when you asign the name to your inputs. To assign values use `=` and do not use `:`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that one. :) One thing that I hate about html codes. It doesn't tell you if there are errors in your code.

Comment: ha ha @Jairo, you need to be more careful with your code next time

Answer (score 0):

first you check $_POST hold some value or not.

so use **print_r($_POST)** above your code ,
it help you to identifies the error,

Comment: i tried doing it. even that code shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

your html should be like this :-

```
   <form method="post" action="CaNeCo_Admin_Reg.php">
   <table width="400">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Log-in Information:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Administrator Type:</td>
     <td>
       <select name="adminType" id="adminType">
       <option value="0">Please Select</option>
       <option value="1">Super Administrator</option>
       <option value="2">Administrator</option>
       <option value="3">Secretary</option>
       <option value="4">Viewer</option>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>User ID: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="userID" id="adminUserID" placeholder="User I.D."         maxlength="20" size="35"/></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Password: </td>
  <td><input type="password" name="userPass" id="adminUserPass" placeholder="Password" maxlength="25" size="35"/></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Repeat Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="repeatPass" id="adminRepeatPass" placeholder="Repeat Password" maxlength="25" size="35"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="25"><b>Personal Information:</b></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>First Name: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="adminFirstName" id="adminFirstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" size="35"/></td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Last Name: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="adminLastName" id="adminLastName" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="25" size="35"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="50"><center><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

For cheking index existing you may use php function like array_key_exists or isset, if index not found you must init variable as empty (null or empty string):

```
if (array_key_exists('adminType', $_POST)) {
    $p_adminType = $_POST['adminType'];
} else {
    $p_adminType = '';
}
if (array_key_exists('userID', $_POST)) {
    $p_adminUserID = $_POST['userID'];
else {
    $p_adminUserID = '';
}
if (array_key_exists('userPass', $_POST)) {
    $p_adminUserPass = $_POST['userPass'];
else {
    $p_adminUserPass = '';
}
if (array_key_exists('adminFirstName', $_POST)) {
    $p_firstName = $_POST['adminFirstName'];
else {
    $p_firstName = '';
}
if (array_key_exists('adminLastName', $_POST)) {
    $p_lastName = $_POST['adminLastName'];
else {
    $p_lastName = '';
}
```

Comment: `array_key_exists` works slower than `isset`.

Comment: For example, `$p_adminType = isset($_POST['adminType']) ? $_POST['adminType'] : '';` is the best.

Comment: Yes, also, isset for $_POST['adminType'] = null will be false. I use current example for more simple view

Comment: There's no possibility that `$_POST` contains **NULL** . Only **string** (including empty string, `""`) or **array** .

Answer (score -1):

By the way, these names seem to be very confusing.

I think you should rewrite these statement:

```
$p_adminType = $_POST['adminType'];
$p_adminUserID = $_POST['userID'];
$p_adminUserPass = $_POST['userPass'];
$p_firstName = $_POST['adminFirstName'];
$p_lastName = $_POST['adminLastName'];
```

into:

```
$p_adminType = $_POST['type'];
$p_adminUserID = $_POST['userID'];
$p_adminUserPass = $_POST['userPass'];
$p_adminFirstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$p_adminLastName = $_POST['lastName'];
```

or:

```
$p_type = $_POST['adminType'];
$p_userID = $_POST['adminUserID'];
$p_userPass = $_POST['adminUserPass'];
$p_firstName = $_POST['adminFirstName'];
$p_lastName = $_POST['adminLastName'];
```

or:

```
$p_type = $_POST['type'];
$p_userID = $_POST['userID'];
$p_userPass = $_POST['userPass'];
$p_firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$p_lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
```

or:

```
$p_adminType = $_POST['adminType'];
$p_adminUserID = $_POST['adminUserID'];
$p_adminUserPass = $_POST['adminUserPass'];
$p_adminFirstName = $_POST['adminFirstName'];
$p_adminLastName = $_POST['adminLastName'];
```

Comment: The reason why my naming scheme is like that is because I find it easier in referencing that way. I tend to have difficulty in remembering variables when they are differently named especially when I already have a lot of variables in my code.